# Required http methods for generic small businesses' web application?

Tags: http

Except `GET` and `POST` methods, should I implement rest of the methods of the `http` such as `HEAD`?
The website is about a small business site, all I'm worry is about search engines and indexing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll need another. I make websites for a living, and I never use HEAD (starting to wonder if I should look into that ;) ).

For a small bussiness, this will do perfectly fine. I hardly run into problems on default configured servers for normal websites.

Searchengines and indexing is content-related. Make sure you have the proper texts/stories/content, with proper html (H1 for title, p for text) etc and you have the basics of seo covered.
SEO has little to do with the methods you use to send data.

Comment: thanks buddy, as an article I was reading, it says the `HEAD' is used for fetching metadata of the page, so I thought it should be implemented too. Does google bot always use `GET` or `POST` too?

Comment: The bot doesnt do post, they only access urls, so that GET. But post is mainly for submitting info, not needed for a bot